# Flip x axis in r for forestplot

Tags: r, statistics, r-forestplot

I've made a foresplot in r using the metafor package with the following code:

```
res <- metafor::rma(cohens_d, variance, data = my_data)


par(mar=c(3.4,0,0,0))
par(cex=2.5, font=4)
metafor::forest.rma(res, alim=c(-3.75, 3.75), xlab = "Cohen's D with 95% CI", 
                slab = my_data$Paper)
```

which gives me the image: 
[image: forestplot]

I'd like to flip the x axis, meaning have the negative on the right. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a really ridiculous hack, but it works. Basically, you have to draw the plot twice, once to add the points (with reversed signs) and once to add the annotations (without the reversed signs).

```
library(metafor)

dat <- get(data(dat.bcg))
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)

### default plot
forest(res, xlim=c(-8,8))

### trick into reverse x-axis
forest(res, xaxt="n", transf=function(x) -1*x, annotate=FALSE, xlim=c(-8,8), xlab="Log Relative Risk")
axis(side=1, at=seq(-3, 3, 1), labels=seq(3,-3,-1))
par(new=TRUE)
forest(res, xaxt="n", xlim=c(-8,8), col="white", border="white", pch=NA, lty="blank", efac=NA, xlab="", slab=NA, mlab=NA)
par(new=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply just flip the estimated coefficients of the model (**b** component of the **rma** class) prior to plotting:

```
res <- metafor::rma(cohens_d, variance, data = my_data)
res$b <- -res$b
```

Comment: This does work, and is probably the simplest solution, though it makes the effect size negative which I'm not crazy about. I'm look more for the -3.75 to be on right and the positive 3.75 to be on left (so axis from left to right goes from max to min instead of min to max ) so that they retain their original values but are just flipped in orientation when viewed.

Comment: Wolfgang's answer seems correct and is similar to what I would have done.